# Preferred way of marking a Java constructor/method as not for client use?

Tags: java, deprecated, setter, default-constructor

I want to mark some default constructors and setters as not available/recommended for use. I need it to be somewhat similar to the annotation `@Deprecated`, but it shouldn't have the same meaning. I'm only adding that constructors and setters because some frameworks are making me do so (Hibernate, Spring, Jackson). Do you know if such construct exists?

Comment: @Deprecated looks like the best option, or maybe if you could make them protected, package-protected or private (don't know if spring or hibernate would let you do that).

Comment: Why wouldn't you want them available for use? If those frameworks require them, it is likely that they will be using them.

Comment: You can create your own annotation with no significance and place it on your constructors/methods. Then it is up to developer to respect your conventions. In my experience developers don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer here is to only expose interfaces and factories outside your API. This allows you to hide the methods that might be required to be non-private due to the framework.

If you cannot do this, try to make the methods default scope (instead of `protected`).

In addition, you might use annotations as an in-house marker. On my project, we have created annotations for this purpose: `PresentForDependancyInjection` and/or `FrameworkEntryPoint`. These are decoration-only annotations but get the point across.

Answer (score 0):

Make them `protected`, that's the method generally used to prevent them being called elsewhere. If the frameworks want them to be `public` then there is little you can do, unless you can configure them to not do so.

Comment: I would think default scope would be better than `protected` as it is more restrictive.

Comment: How is it more restrictive? Default is package level, protected is only same class and children; `private` is more restrictive, not default.

Comment: protected is package level as well as sub-classes. It would be easy to mark a class as a sub-class of a libraries class, however would be really odd to declare a package for another company / project to be able to use package scope. Not perfect, but better.

Comment: My bad, I remembered Java's `protected` as being equal to C++'s (inheritors only).

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand you want to find a way to deal with some frameworks requirements without hassle ? You would like to avoid the Java Bean naming convention while being able to see your code handled by such frameworks ?As far as I know it's not possible using the plain Java language, you may use AOP / bytecode enhancement tools to decorate your classes to be compatible with such frameworks.... This may work but it has different drawbacks:
- increase complexity
- maintenance may be tricky 
You may use personal annotations to guide the bytecode enhancement....

Another point of view would be to use a fractal approach , but this framework is not well known even if it's one of the most impressive I know. You may have a look here : http://fractal.ow2.org/java.html

HTH
jerome